# Issue related to not Equal to (<>) in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following code in SQL Server,

```
declare @previouspulse int = 0
declare @previousox int = 0
declare @Pulse int = 0
declare @SpO2 int = 0

set @previouspulse = null  
set @Pulse= 121
set @previousox = 56 
set @SpO2 = null

IF @previouspulse <> @Pulse or @previousox <> @SpO2 
    select -1
else
    select -2
```

i am getting result -2 from above code

my question is that:

if  symbol `<>`  means `not equal to` then  i should get result `-1` instead `-2`

so in condition, in above code, if one of the condition satisfied in if condition then i should get result -1  and in my case i am getting `true` in both confition, if symbol `'<>'` means `'Not Equal to(!=)'`

so does it really that the symbol `'<>'` means `'Not Equal to(!=)'` ???

Thanks

Comment: The compare operators do not work for `null` values. You have to use the `IS` operator for that.

Comment: @Aishvarya: the standard SQL "not equals" operator **is** `<>` But `!=` is accepted by all(?) DBMS as an alternative. There is absolutely no difference whatsoever between the two - especially with regards to NULL handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NULL values represent missing or unknown data.It is not possible to test for NULL values with comparison operators, such as =, <, or <> because comparison with unknown data results in an unknown data.

Use ISNULL operator to get correct results from comparison as:

```
declare @previouspulse int = 0
declare @previousox int = 0
declare @Pulse int = 0
declare @SpO2 int = 0

set @previouspulse = null  
set @Pulse= 121
set @previousox = 56 
set @SpO2 = null

IF isnull(@previouspulse,0) <> isnull(@Pulse,0) or isnull(@previousox,0) <> isnull(@SpO2,0)
    select -1
else
    select -2
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the reason why,

```
@previouspulse <> @Pulse OR @previousox <> @SpO2
              NULL       OR            NULL
                        NULL
```

since you have only two paths, it falls on `FALSE` block which results to `-2`. Whn comparing with `NULL` value use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

- [SQL Three-Valued Logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ISNULL function before you compare the variables

```
declare @previouspulse int = 0
declare @previousox int = 0
declare @Pulse int = 0
declare @SpO2 int = 0

set @previouspulse = null  
set @Pulse= 121
set @previousox = 56 
set @SpO2 = null

IF ISNULL(@previouspulse,0) <> @Pulse or @previousox <> ISNULL(@SpO2,0)
    select -1
else
    select -2
```